# Images import from assets folder in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

A direct image import is working, but with object type is not working.
why this occurred?
I'm using "react": "^16.12.0", "typescript": "~3.7.2"

```
// ./src/assets/babys/Babyimages.tsx

const BabyImages = [
  { img: '../assets/babys/1.png', age: 1, name: 'name1' },
  { img: '../assets/babys/2.png', age: 1, name: 'name2' },
  ...
];
export default BabyImages;


// ./src/component/Home.tsx
    ...
    import BabyImages from '../assets/babys/BabyImages';
    import SampleImage from '../assets/babys/1.png';   // this direct image importing is working
    ...

    const tileData = BabyImages.map(data => {
      return { img: data.img, age: data.age, name: data.name };
    });

    export default function TestFunction() {
     ...

    return (
    ...
      <img src={SampleImage} alt="" />     // <----- so,this is working!!
            {tileData.map(tile => (     //<------ but it's not working!
        <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.name} />
        <GridListTileBar
          title={tile.age}
          subtitle={<span>baby: {tile.name}</span>}
        />
    ...
    ))}
  );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What's the error that you're seeing?

Comment: Please add your error.

Comment: No any error sign shown, just try to show images by map method from Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample one is working because you've imported it directly and webpack will know to pack it up and correctly reference relative to `public/index.html` it in the outputed build.

In the code below you're basically just doing `src="../assets/babys/1.png"` which doesn't mean anything to the `public/index.html` unless there is an `assets` folder positioned at that relative route to it and the dev server has permission to access it.

The easiest way to handle this is to just do:

```js
// ./src/assets/babys/Babyimages.tsx
import BabyImage1 from '../assets/babys/1.png'; 
import BabyImage2 from '../assets/babys/2.png'; 

const BabyImages = [
  { img: BabyImage1, age: 1, name: 'name1' },
  { img: BabyImage2, age: 1, name: 'name2' },
  ...
];
export default BabyImages;
```

Comment: thanks, I forgot the image importing to reference before to export. :)